# Preposition “a” before a pronoun

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I saw a sentence that read: *A lui piace il tè*.  I could not find an explanation for the use of *a* before *lui*.

Comment: A relevant question: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/using-piace-in-a-how-many-question  
A slightly less relevant one: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/the-verb-piacere-with-collective-nouns  
TL;DR: This is how the verb *piacere* is constructed in Italian (something *piace a* someone).

Comment: To make things worse, it could (or even should) be *gli piace il tè*.

Answer (score 6):

There are two sources for confusion:

1. the subject is at the end
2. *piacere* has a very peculiar construction in Italian

In the sentence the subject is *il tè*; it's similar to *Roberto piace ad Alice* (which in English would be *Alice likes Bob*). So Italian places the person that actually likes somebody/something as the grammatical indirect object.

When this grammatical indirect object is a pronoun, usually the word order becomes

> ⟨indirect object pronoun⟩ piace ⟨subject⟩

and the pronoun is normally in weak form *mi*, *ti*, *gli*, *ci*, *vi*, *gli*.<sup>1</sup> So it should really be

> *Gli piace il tè*

The long form would be used if there's some opposition to be underlined:

> *A lui piace il tè, a lei il caffè*

(in the second part, the verb *piace* is implied).

---

<sup>1</sup> I *know* that grammars prescribe a postponed *loro* instead of *gli* for the third person plural. But it's much more common in spoken and also in written language to use *gli* both for the plural and the singular.

Comment: I agree with your answer and upvoted it. But I would like to add that some people (like me) still prefer: A loro piace il tè. Must be old age.

Comment: @alsa Probably I'd say the same, especially in case of ambiguities about the number of people *gli* refers to.

Answer (score 4):

The literal meaning of the sentence is

> Tea is pleasant to him

which is how *He likes tea* is usually expressed in Italian. Here the preposition *a* is the exact translation of the preposition *to* in English: it introduces what's called the *complemento di termine* or in English *indirect object*. See for example *Parlo a lui*, "I speak to him" or *Ho dato quel libro a mia sorella*, "I've given that book to my sister".

For more  detailed on how to translate the verb *to like* in Italian see the excellent answer linked by DaG in the comments.