# What is the difference among "da cui" , "di cui", "a cui"?

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions

I can't distinguish the difference! I know meaning of "da", "di" and "a" separately, but I can't imagine perfectly the whole meaning with "cui". for example am I right here with these suppositions?

> Il telefonino è un oggetto *con cui* / *per cui* chiamiamo.
>
> La spiaggia è una posta *da cui* mi piace.
>
> Arrivare tardi è un comportameno *a cui* / *di cui*  non piacciono nessuno.
>
> La Pausa è un momento *per cui* puo usare a risposarmi.
>
> Fare rumore con la carta al cinema è una cosa *di cui* dobbiamo evitare.

Comment: Hint: try constructing the sentence in a direct way, and then change it to the relative form. For instance: *Chiamiamo **con** il telefonino* > *Il telefonino è  un oggetto **con cui** chiamiamo*. Can you do the other sentences (which, I am afraid, are all wrong)? For instance: *Mi piace la spiaggia* (not *dalla spiaggia*) > *La spiaggia è un posto **che** mi piace* (*posto* is “place”; *posta* is “mail” or “post office”).

Comment: As for the peculiar construction of the verbo *piacere*, check http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/using-piace-in-a-how-many-question and http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/the-verb-piacere-with-collective-nouns .

Comment: Ohh! yeah! I thought we have gender inflection for "posto"!

Comment: I just found about preposition for "piacere" (which I knew; e.g, A mi piace...). But here I was wrong. Could you please correct me about other sentences?

Comment: You didn't know them exceedingly well... :-) It is *A me piace* or *Mi piace*, not **A mi piace*.

Comment: Yes, that's right! That's what makes this structure completely different from Spanish, because they say: " a mi me gusta!" totally different than Italian, since it was long time I couldn't precisely continue Italian, I made the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest trying to construct the sentence in a direct way, and then change it to the relative form.

As for your sentences:

> *Chiamiamo **con** il telefonino.* > *Il telefonino è un oggetto **con cui** chiamiamo.*
>
> *Mi piace **la** spiaggia.* (not *dalla spiaggia*) > *La spiaggia è un posto **che** mi piace* (posto is “place”; posta is “mail” or “post office”)
>
> *A nessuno piace XXX.* > *XXX è un comportamen**t**o **che** non piac**e a** nessuno.*

The sentence about the *pausa* is to be completely rewritten, and I'll do so twice.

> *Posso usare la pausa per riposarmi.* > *La pausa è un momento **che** posso usare per riposarmi.*
>
> *Mi posso riposare **durante la** pausa.* > *La pausa è un momento **durante cui** posso riposarmi.*

The last sentence is a bit tricky, since you use *evitare* in two different ways: *evitare **di** fare qualcosa* (“avoid doing something”) and *evitare qualcosa* (“avoid something”), the latter without prepositions. So:

> *Dobbiamo evitare **di** fare rumore...*, but *Fare rumore... è una cosa **che** dobbiamo evitare.*